# How to show the span data by dynamic in the data grid using WPF C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF Development.

Please bear me if i asked Similar question

I need to populate the grid like below

### DeviceName  Model  Version  Status         Operation

Samsung     g101   4.2     Connected   [PlayImg] [Stopimg]

Nokia      920     5.0     Discovered    [DiscoveredImg]

If deviced connected to application then only we need to Playimage and Stopimage

Otherwise we need to show only image discovered.

How to achieve this WPF?

Please refer below which makes clear

[image]

Comment: you will need to share what have to tried and your code where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to add three `bool` properties and use a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` on each of the three `Image` controls, as @progpow has hinted:

In `Resources`:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

In XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    <Image Source="/YourAppName;component/Images/Stop.png" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsStopVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Image Source="/YourAppName;component/Images/Play.png" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsPlayVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
    <Image Source="/YourAppName;component/Images/Discovered.png" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsDiscoveredVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

You could then control whether the various images should display by setting the three `bool` properties to true or false:

```
IsStopVisible = IsPlayVisible = true;
IsDiscoveredVisible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you so much man!!. One doubt we can able to fire the event handler from image tag na

Answer (score 1):

I think you must add three buttons and set visible related to connected